# PHP 7.1 on Docker PDO Driver not installed - Verified it is on the image

Tags: php, mysql, docker, pdo, dockerfile

I am always getting an error that `PDO driver not found`. I tried restarting, installing PDO extensions directly. Note that this docker setup works on my Linux box last night. Only difference is I did it from scratch compared to on my Windows box I already has images.

After getting the error initially I tried to remove the images, the base PHP image failed to remove for some reason.  I then ran:

1. `docker exec -it php sh`
2. `docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql`

Running that command explains that the extensions were already installed. But I still receive the error.

I also noticed this is present along with the modules:

```
/var/www/html # ls /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/                                
docker-php-ext-pdo_mysql.ini                                                 
/var/www/html # cat /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-pdo_mysql.ini   
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

**DockerFile PHP**

```
FROM php:7.1-fpm-alpine
RUN apk update \
   && docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql \
   && chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html \
   && sed -ri 's/^www-data:x:82:82:/www-data:x:1000:50:/' /etc/passwd
```

**PHP Modules on Docker Container**

```
PS C:> docker exec -it php sh      
/var/www/html # php -m                                                                 
[PHP Modules]                                                                          
Core                                                                                   
ctype                                                                                  
curl                                                                                   
date                                                                                   
dom                                                                                    
fileinfo                                                                               
filter                                                                                 
ftp                                                                                    
hash                                                                                    
iconv                                                                                  
json                                                                                   
libxml                                                                                 
mbstring                                                                               
mysqlnd                                                                                
openssl                                                                                
pcre                                                                                   
PDO                                                                                    
pdo_mysql                                                                              
pdo_sqlite                                                                             
Phar                                                                                   
posix                                                                                  
readline                                                                               
Reflection                                                                             
session                                                                                
SimpleXML                                                                               
SPL                                                                                    
sqlite3                                                                                
standard                                                                               
tokenizer                                                                              
xml                                                                                    
xmlreader                                                                              
xmlwriter                                                                              
zlib                                                                                                                                                                          
[Zend Modules]
```

**SysInfo**

- Windows 10 Pro
- Docker version 17.06.0-ce, build 02c1d87

Comment: Try and remove the image, make sure that any containers based on this image are stopped and removed.

Comment: I did try that but still have an issue. As you can see the php modules are listed as installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did use to see the already installed message when I ran docker build but it still built the image fine for me.

https://github.com/fire015/docker/blob/master/php-fpm-71/Dockerfile

Try building it from fresh using `docker build --no-cache=true`

Answer (score 0):

NONE of the above worked for me until I gave the image a tag when calling docker build and referenced that tag as the image in the docker-compose.yml file.

e.g.

```
PS C:\Users\Grrarth\dev\docker> docker build --no-cache=true .
```

FAILED where

```
PS C:\Users\Grrarth\dev\docker> docker build --no-cache=true -t MyImageName .
```

combined with the following (instead of using the standard image file name) in the docker-compose.yml file:

```
services:
  app:
    image: MyImageName
    ...
```

WORKS a treat.

I know it sounds obvious to experienced docker users but I have not seen anyone point it out for us newbies.